# Most efficient PyQt Model selection in big trees

Tags: pyqt, pyside, multipleselection, model-view

I'm currently selecting multiple rows in a model tree with the code below.
But it can be really slow in big sessions with loads of nodes.
I suspect this is not very efficient as it's probably selecting the rows one by one. Is there anything that could speed things up - for example don't refresh while selecting until the last one or select all in one call?

```py
selectionModel = self.tree.selectionModel()
selectionModel.clear()

for node, i in self.tree.model().iterNodeAndIndexs():
    if nodeCondition:
        selectionModel.select(i, selectionModel.Select | selectionModel.Rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [Model/View Programming Guide](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#using-a-selection-model) you can put the top-left and bottom-right indices in a `QItemSelection` and so select all cells at once.

Note that for hierarchical models you will have to make the selection at all levels of the tree recursively (see the [selecting all notes section](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#selecting-all-items-in-a-model)). Something like this:

```py
def mySelectRows(treeView, parentIndex=None, topRow=0, bottomRow=None):

    if parentIndex is None:
        parentIndex = QtCore.QModelIndex()

    model = treeView.model()
    totalSelection = QtGui.QItemSelection()

    def populateSelection(parentIndex, topRow=0, bottomRow=None):

        if bottomRow is None:
            bottomRow = model.rowCount(parentIndex)

        leftCol, rightCol = 0, model.columnCount(parentIndex)

        topLeft = model.index(topRow, leftCol, parentIndex)
        bottomRight = model.index(bottomRow-1, rightCol-1, parentIndex)
        newSelection = QtGui.QItemSelection(topLeft, bottomRight)
        totalSelection.merge(newSelection, QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.Select)

        for row in range(topRow, bottomRow):
            childIndex = model.index(row, 0, parentIndex)
            if model.rowCount(childIndex) > 0:
                populateSelection(childIndex)

    # Start recursion
    populateSelection(parentIndex, topRow=topRow, bottomRow=bottomRow)
    selectionModel = treeView.selectionModel()
    selectionModel.select(totalSelection, 
                          QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.ClearAndSelect)
```

Depending on your implementation of the model it may be faster to replace `if model.rowCount(childIndex) > 0` with `if model.hasChildren(childIndex)`

Comment: You can use [`QItemSelection.merge()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemselection.html#merge) to join multiple selections together. Does that allow you to avoid recursion and thus avoid repeated calls to `selectionModel.select()`?

Comment: @three_pineapples. No, you still need the recursion (as the documentation states), otherwise only the top level items will be selected. However, it is an improvement since the multiple calls to `selectionModel.select()` are probably what make it slow (and cause the `selectionModel.selectionChanged` signal to be emitted repeatedly). I updated my code to use `selectionModel.select()`. Thanks.