# How to improve selection performance with PySide.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel and QTreeView?

Tags: python, performance, pyside, qtreeview

I've run into a problem that has me stumped and I'm wondering if there are any known workarounds.  It seems that performing selections on *QTreeView* that uses a subclassed *QAbstractItemView* can be very, very slow.

Case in point; I modified the sample file that is installed with PySide:

`..\site-packages\PySide\examples\itemviews\simpletreemodel\simpletreemodel.py` to have ~4000 rows of data item, up from the original 40.

I also set the tree view to `QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectionMode.ExtendedSelection`.  Running this results in gui interaction that is sluggish at best and very slow when "large" selections are made. This is true via mouse operations, keyboard operations, and script operations.

Regarding the latter, I added a `view.selectAll()` to the modified script and profiled it to show that it took ~84 seconds to select all of the items.

I'm considering disabling selections and writing my own custom *Selection_Manager* to see if I can speed things up manually. Does anyone have any other suggestions or ideas/examples on how to make the standard workflow faster?

Thanks in advance.

Here is script that exhibits this issue.

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

NUMBER_OF_ITEMS = 1000
NUMBER_OF_CHILDREN_PER_ITEM = 4

class TreeItem(object):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        self.parentItem = parent
        self.itemData = data
        self.childItems = []

    def appendChild(self, item):
        self.childItems.append(item)

    def child(self, row):
        return self.childItems[row]

    def childCount(self):
        return len(self.childItems)

    def columnCount(self):
        return len(self.itemData)

    def data(self, column):
        try:
            return self.itemData[column]
        except IndexError:
            return None

    def parent(self):
        return self.parentItem

    def row(self):
        if self.parentItem:
            return self.parentItem.childItems.index(self)

        return 0


class TreeModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, num=NUMBER_OF_ITEMS, num_of_children=NUMBER_OF_CHILDREN_PER_ITEM, parent=None):
        super(TreeModel, self).__init__(parent)

        self.rootItem = TreeItem( ["Title"] )
        self.setupModelData( self.rootItem, num=num, num_of_children=num_of_children )

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        if parent.isValid():
            return parent.internalPointer().columnCount()
        else:
            return self.rootItem.columnCount()

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None

        item = index.internalPointer()

        return item.data(index.column())

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.NoItemFlags

        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.rootItem.data(section)

        return None

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        if not parent.isValid():
            parentItem = self.rootItem
        else:
            parentItem = parent.internalPointer()

        childItem = parentItem.child(row)
        if childItem:
                return self.createIndex(row, column, childItem)
        else:
                return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        childItem = index.internalPointer()
        parentItem = childItem.parent()

        if parentItem == self.rootItem:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        return self.createIndex(parentItem.row(), 0, parentItem)

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        if parent.column() > 0:
                return 0

        if not parent.isValid():
            parentItem = self.rootItem
        else:
            parentItem = parent.internalPointer()

        return parentItem.childCount()

    def setupModelData(self, parent, num=100, num_of_children=10, ):
        """
        Simple test method to fill the Model with items.
        """
        for i in range( num ):
            data = [ '{0}.Item'.format( i ) ]
            item = TreeItem( data, parent )
            parent.appendChild( item )

            for j in range( num_of_children ):
                data = [ '{0}.{1}.Child'.format( i, j ) ]
                child = TreeItem( data, item )
                item.appendChild( child )

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = TreeModel( num=NUMBER_OF_ITEMS, num_of_children=NUMBER_OF_CHILDREN_PER_ITEM )

    view = QtGui.QTreeView()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.setSelectionMode( QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectionMode.ExtendedSelection )
    view.expandAll()
    view.setWindowTitle("Simple Tree Model")
    view.show()
    view.selectAll()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please don't link to Dropbox but include the code directly in your question. It would be even better if you'd make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You will get a lot more help if we can just copy-paste-run your example code without special instructions.

Comment: Sure.  I inlined a streamlined version of the script, removing its external dependencies.  I had thought it would be useful to compare against a script that installs with PySide, but perhaps not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing what I suggested, disabling selection in the QTreeView and managing selections myself.  The select all time dropped down to about 2 seconds.  Still high imo, but much better.

```
my_qtreeview.setSelectionMode( QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectionMode.NoSelection )
```

My full solution isn't decomposed and modular to the point of posting anything immediately reusable here, but perhaps this snippet will be helpful to anyone interested.

A few notes:

- I have custom python Nodes in my QAbstractItemModel.  I leverage a ".selected" in each to store its selected state.
- In the overriden QAbstractItemModel.data() method, when a 'node.selected=True' I set its background color to something that indicates the row is selected.
- I ended up needing to handle keyboard modifiers manually. I also needed to track the item clicked on vs the item release on. I also toss out any non-left mouse clicks from being considered for selections. I do this in mousePressEvent() and mouseReleaseEvent() in a subclassed QTreeView.
- I have multiple columns, some being icons that should not be selected when clicked but rather toggle some property on an object the the view is showing. [screenshot of my treeview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnESz.png)
- on_tree_clicked_left() below lives in the parent of the QTreeView and is triggered via a custom signal in the QTreeView.

Here is my core code sample that should convey the gist of what I'm doing:

```
def on_tree_clicked_left( self, index_start, index_end, keyboard_modifiers ):
    """
    :param index_start: QtCore.QModelIndex
    :param index_end: QtCore.QModelIndex
    :param keyboard_modifiers: QtGui.QApplication.keyboardModifiers
    """
    if ( index_start is None and index_end is None ) or \
        not index_start.isValid() or not index_end.isValid():
        self.model_data_objs.deselect_all()
        return None

    if index_start is None:
        index_start = index_end

    start_node  = index_start.model().mapToSource( index_start ).internalPointer()
    end_node    = index_end.model().mapToSource( index_end ).internalPointer()

    # get the nodes to operate on ...
    nodes = [ start_node ]
    if not index_start == index_end:
        nodes_above = list()
        nodes_below = list()
        index_above = self.gui_tree.indexAbove( index_start )
        index_below = self.gui_tree.indexBelow( index_start )

        while not end_node in nodes_above and not end_node in nodes_below:
            if index_above.isValid():
                node_after = index_above.model().mapToSource( index_above ).internalPointer()
                nodes_above.append( node_after )

                index_above = self.gui_tree.indexAbove( index_above )

            if index_below.isValid():
                node_before = index_below.model().mapToSource( index_below ).internalPointer()
                nodes_below.append( node_before )

                index_below = self.gui_tree.indexBelow( index_below )

        if end_node in nodes_above:
            nodes += nodes_above
        if end_node in nodes_below:
            nodes += nodes_below

    # get the operation, based on index_start column ...
    clicked_column = index_start.column()
    if not clicked_column == 0:
        attr    = COLUMNS[ clicked_column ].get( 'attr_name' )
    else:
        attr    = 'selected'
        if not keyboard_modifiers == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier and \
            not keyboard_modifiers == QtCore.Qt.AltModifier:
            self.model_data_objs.deselect_all()

    # perform the operation
    new_value = not getattr( start_node, attr )
    for node in nodes:
        setattr( node, attr, new_value )
```

Answer (score 1):

I've run your example using the [Python profiler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html). In total it took about 86 seconds, 51 of those are spend by the `index` method of `list` objects. Here is the output of the profiler, ordered by time and cut off at 10 functions.

```
Wed Dec 23 12:30:15 2015    stats.dat

         21859835 function calls (21859832 primitive calls) in 86.528 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 110 to 10 due to restriction <10>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  3038204   51.266    0.000   51.266    0.000 {method 'index' of 'list' objects}
        1   14.445   14.445   84.939   84.939 {exec_}
  3053317    9.016    0.000   70.051    0.000 main.py:94(parent)
  3060258    4.769    0.000    4.769    0.000 {method 'createIndex' of 'PySide.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel' objects}
  3038204    2.383    0.000   53.649    0.000 main.py:36(row)
  3168995    1.409    0.000    1.409    0.000 {method 'isValid' of 'PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex' objects}
        1    1.187    1.187   86.528   86.528 main.py:2(<module>)
  3053317    0.776    0.000    0.776    0.000 main.py:33(parent)
  3121496    0.525    0.000    0.525    0.000 {method 'internalPointer' of 'PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex' objects}
    22054    0.189    0.000    0.333    0.000 {method 'hasIndex' of 'PySide.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel' objects}
```

The `list.index()` method is called in `TreeItem.row()`. So to determine the row number of an item, the children list of its parent is traversed until the item is found. This always struck me as inefficient but so far I have never had performance issues with it.

It therefore seems that a possible optimization would be to store the row number in the `TreeItem`. This of course uses extra memory and you need to make sure it stays consistent if you update the tree.

Another angle is to investigate why the `row` and `index` functions are called so often (about three million times, which seems a lot to me). Perhaps you can find out by looking in the Qt source code of `QTreeView.selectAll`.

Good luck and let me know if you find a solution.

p.s. I've made a QItemSelection by hand in the past, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30302816/625350). I don't think it will help you.